# Too late to get first postMessage? Order of events with respect to message and load events

Tags: javascript

From my parent window, I send a message to my iframe when I get the `DOMContentLoaded` event of my iframe:

```
iframe.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    iframe.postMessage('blah');
});
```

In my iframe, I am setting up a listener for postMessage on `DOMContentLoaded`:

```
function msgHandler(e) {
     console.log('incoming message:', e.data);
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    window.addEventListener('message', msgHandler, false);
});
```

So right now things work. The iframe `msgHandler` is getting the `blah` message even though I set up the message listener in DOMContentLoaded. I was surprised because I expected that I should have first setup the message listener in the iframe and THEN have my parent window send a message.

What is the order of events with respect to load events and message events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent page and iFrame run in different threads in the browser. So the ready event can run concurrently.

When the iFrame receives the message from the parent it is just added to the back of the queue of events to process. Given that is will be received after the domReady event this will work even if the code to setup this listener is still in the queue to run, as it will be further up the stack queue.

Comment: Oh interesting, I suspected this. Thanks!